# R - how to pass formula to a with(df, glm(y ~ x)) construction inside a function

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm using the `mice` package in R to multiply-impute some missing data.  I need to be able to specify a formula that is passed to a `with(df, glm(y ~ x))` construction inside of a function.  This `with()` construction is the format used by the `mice` package to fit the regression model separately within *each* of the imputed datasets.

However, I cannot figure out the scoping problems preventing me from successfully passing the formula as an argument.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(mice)

data(mtcars)
mtcars[5, 5] <- NA # introduce a missing value to be imputed

mtcars.imp = mice(mtcars, m = 5)

# works correctly outside of function
with(mtcars.imp, glm(mpg ~ cyl))

fit_model_mi = function(formula) {
  with(mtcars.imp, glm(formula))
}

# doesn't work when trying to pass formula into function   
fit_model_mi("mpg ~ cyl")
```

Also see [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-pass-a-model-formula-as-argument-to-with-mids-td2552090.html) for the same question being asked on R help, although it does not receive an answer.

Comment: `"mpg ~ cyl"` is not a formula object. It just a character value Furthermore the `with` function is only safe to use at the console level. It's use inside functions is specifically advised against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the formula in as.formula

```
fit_model_mi = function(formula) {
    with(mtcars.imp, glm(as.formula(formula)) )
}
```

Seems to work:

```
> fit_model_mi("mpg ~ cyl")
call :
with.mids(data = mtcars.imp, expr = glm(as.formula(formula)))

call1 :
mice(data = mtcars, m = 5)

nmis :
 mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0 

analyses :
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(formula))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl  
     37.885       -2.876  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
Null Deviance:      1126 
Residual Deviance: 308.3    AIC: 169.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `attach` your data by

```
attach(mtcars)
```

Result shown

```
fit_model_mi("mpg ~ cyl")
call :
with.mids(data = mtcars.imp, expr = glm(formula))

call1 :
mice(data = mtcars, m = 5)

nmis :
 mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0 

analyses :
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = formula)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl  
     37.885       -2.876  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
Null Deviance:      1126 
Residual Deviance: 308.3    AIC: 169.3
```