# Data objects not found in embedded vegan:cca. Scoping issue?

Tags: r, scoping, vegan

I try to embed `cca` (and also `capscale`) from package **vegan** (version 2.5-7, R 4.1.2) in another function to test an analysis pipeline with some data transformation and then varying model formulas. The used data matrices (e.g. `bio` and `env`) can have different names and are normally not visible in the global work space. The error that I get is:

```
Error in eval(match.call()$data, environment(formula), enclos = .GlobalEnv) : 
object 'env' not found
```

that looks like a scoping issue. Looking around, it seems that **vegan** had some problems with scoping in the past that are [said to be fixed](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/100), so I wonder if I overlooked something. Any workaround is also welcome, e.g. environment manipulation.

```r
library("vegan")

## create some example data
set.seed(123)
bio <- matrix(sample(0:10, 50, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
env <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1:10, 10),
  y = 1:10 + rnorm(10),
  z = rnorm(10)
)
cca(bio ~ x + y, data = env) # works

## enclose cca with some other stuff in a function
foo <- function(model, bio, env) {
  ## do preparatory data transformation
  fm <- cca(model, data = env)
  print(fm)
  ## do something else
}

model <- formula(bio ~ x + y) # works
foo(model, bio=bio, env=env)

## now rename data to test scoping
bio2 <- bio
env2 <- env
rm(bio, env)

foo(model, bio = bio2, env = env2) # error
# Error in eval(match.call()$data, environment(formula), enclos = .GlobalEnv) :
# object 'env' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, looks to be a scoping issue. I think the key is to update the formula's environment inside the function:

```
foo <- function(model, bio, env) {
  # update model environment
  environment(model) = environment()
  ## do preparatory data transformation
  fm <- cca(model, data = env)
  print(fm)
  ## do something else
}
```

Comment: Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710353/1199289

Comment: Yes, updating the environment is the thing to do. We used to do it all the time in some vegan functions, but have since made the scoping more robust. However, if you first define a model and then in another environment add new things, the original model cannot know about these.

Comment: Another thing is that instead of environment-bound formula, you may use the matrix interface `cca(Y, XModelMatrix)`: this is what we currently use within vegan in similar situations. Function `vegan:::anova.ccabyterm` shows how to do that generally (i.e., using the same function for cca, rda, dbrda) with `ordConstrained(Y, X, Z, method="pass")` which completely avoids the environment-dependency of formula.